# Cannot connect to different container in docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I tried an nginx + react front end to talk with a gunicorn + flask backend with the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   ner:
       build: ./src_python
       command: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 server:app --preload
       expose:
           - 5000
   frontend:
       build:
           context: .
           dockerfile: Dockerfile
       ports:
           - 80:80
       stdin_open: true
       depends_on:
           - ner
```

The Dockerfile for front end

```
FROM node:14-alpine3.12 AS build_stage
WORKDIR /
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY src ./src
COPY public ./public
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=build_stage /build/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        index index.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /api/v1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/v1;
    }
    location /api/v2 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/v2;
    }
}
```

However, while running, I saw the following in the log stream of docker-compose
`frontend_1  | 2020/08/19 13:57:36 [error] 29#29: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/v2?query=watch%20harry%20potter%20vs%20read%20harry%20potter HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v2?query=watch%20harry%20potter%20vs%20read%20harry%20potter", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/?query=watch%20harry%20potter%20vs%20read%20harry%20potter"`

I suspect that I configured nginx or the frontend wrongly, as `docker logs -f backend_container_id` does not show anything about refusing a connection.

If it helps, here is an excerpt of package.json

```
{
  "name": "short_text_understand",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ...
    ],
    "development": [
     ...
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
 ...
  }
}
```

How could I fix that?

Comment: Shouldn't `proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/api/v1;` be  `proxy_pass http://ner:5000/api/v1;` ? localhost refers to the container running nginx and port 5000 is opened on your other service container.

Comment: Please make that an answer so that I can accept @Zeitounator